# Google Cloud Monitoring: Restart a process automatically when detecting error

Tags: monitoring, google-cloud-platform

I'm using Google Cloud Monitoring (Stackdriver) for endpoing check. It's very useful but I need to restart a process manually after receiving an alert. Does anybody have any good idea?

---

update1

monit looks nice.

https://mmonit.com/monit/

Answer (score 1):

http://supervisord.org/ is an option which is preferred by various developers but there is no such default solution to my knowledge.

It would be a great feature for stackdriver though. Whenever it detects a failure it can run a failsafe script on the machine as a privileged user.